# Как правильно задавать зависимостей в pom.xml на дочерних модулях?

Tags: maven

Есть maven проект. К примеру есть `pom.xml` родительского проекта `parentProject` с зависимостью `junit`, и есть модуль `child` в нём зависимость от `mysql`.

Вопрос в том, как обозначать зависимости в многомодульном `maven` проекте? Прописывать их в модулях по мере необходимости или сразу все разместить в `pom.xml` проекта `parentProjects`?

Я думаю, что разница есть, потому что если я размещу `mysql` зависимость в `pom.xml` родительского проекта `parentProjects`, то все остальные модули унаследуют её, даже те которые в ней не нуждаются. Хотя наверное можно как-то исключить зависимость из потомка.

Но зачем исключать если можно и не наследовать её!? Верно ли я размышляю? И если нет, то как это делается в реальных многомодульных проектах?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Общие зависимости можете включить в родительском `pom.xml`, а другие в каждый дочерний `pom.xml`. Этот вариант лучше чем исключать зависимостей потом на дочерний `pom.xml`'ах.

Но если скажем у вас есть 5 модулей и только в одном из них не повторяется одна зависимость, то в этом случае лучше включить эту зависимость в родительском `pom.xml` и потом исключить в том модуле где она не повторяется.